# SessionFactory "Database was not configured through Database method"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, iis-10

I am trying to deploy an API application on IIS 10 with Visual Studio Community 2015 and when I try to publish it I get this error :

"An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.\r\n\r\n  * Database was not configured through Database method.\r\n"

I downloaded the source from [here](https://github.com/accept-project/accept-api).

This is my hibernate configuration in Web.config:

```
 <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>      
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=DEV01\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ACCEPT_DB;Integrated Security=True</property>
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">10</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>      
      <property name="command_timeout">60</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>     
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Here the NHibernateSessionFactory:

```
private NhibernateSessionFactory()
{
    var baseConfig = new Configuration();
    baseConfig.Configure();

    //having one mapping class path is enough.
    var config = Fluently.Configure(baseConfig).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RoleMap>()).ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.Properties.Add("use_outer_join", "true"));

    try
    {
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbSchemaDrop"].CompareTo("1") == 0)
            config.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Drop(false, true));
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbSchemaCreate"].CompareTo("1") == 0)
            config.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true));
        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbSchemaUpdate"].CompareTo("1") == 0)
            config.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw (e);
    }

    SessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();                     
}
```

I had a look to all the other solution I could find on Internet but found nothing that could solve my problem. Also I cannot see any InnerExceptions...

Does Anyone have a solution to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Raise an issue to its owners https://github.com/accept-project/accept-api/issues

Comment: I did so but didn't get any answer. It's an old project and I'm not sure it's still supported... No ideas about my problem?